# bash trap debug failure

Tags: bash

This program (debug shell) works only if you run it like this:

> debug_shell script.sh

If you have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/debug_shell
echo my program
```

Then it doesn't work.

Source for the "debug_shell":

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extdebug
function on_debug {
  echo HERE:  $BASH_ARGV
}
trap on_debug DEBUG
. $1
```

Any idea why it doesn't work (bash 3.2.25)?

Comment: The shebang line is meant to be a specification of the command interpreter required. Your `debug_shell` isn't a command interpreter

Comment: I would be very cautious about adding stuff to `/bin` (or `/usr/bin`).  You could/should use `/usr/local/bin`, probably, or `$HOME/bin`.

Comment: yes, they are all executable (and where it's located is irrelevant/unconstructive).   indeed, it looks like bash *ignores* the shebang... and executes script.sh directly... you see no echo command at all.  is bash looking at debug_shell... realizing that it is, in fact, bash... and then doing something weird? i put an echo "HERE" at the top of debug_shell ... and it doesn't come out!

Comment: i think i figured out that bash is seeing the bin bash at the top and executing the other script as a "subshell"... subverting the purpose in it.  i'm doing it in perl instead

Comment: @pavium my script is the command interpreter... that's the point...it only works explicitly ... not as the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `debug_shell` and `script.sh` have executable bit. Also it's important how you run your script:

```
$ ./script.sh
HERE: ./script.sh
my program
```

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu 10.04 bash 4.1.5, your stuff works fine.

Are you sure your script.sh is executable ?
And be sure you stored the debug_script in /bin of course ;)